# Xcode File management. What is best practice?

Tags: xcode

I've been using Xcode for a while now. One thing that always bugs me is the way it handles files. I like to have my files all in nested folders rather than one big physical folder, but when you create a group in Xcode by default it does not create a folder just a virtual folder within the project.

I can see that virtual folders are great for linking code in arbitrary places into your project but once you get beyond a few classes I find the one big folder approach really painful. And then if you try to fix it later it takes ages and is easy to break your build.

Is it possible to change this behaviour so that by default it creates a physical folder? Or am I doing it wrong and trying to cling to some other way of working? How do other people work with files in Xcode?

Comment: You are clinging, but alas, I cling too. I don't think there is a way to change it; I tend to set up all my folders when I first create a project, then try my best to remember to create physical folder when I need them.

Comment: Where I find it really bites is if I want to copy a part of my project elsewhere. As there was no physical structure I lose the hierarchy in  a new project. It makes for a really ugly repository as well. I guess like you I'll continue creating physical folders as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Remove all the files from the project. Select All and press Delete, and click the Delete File References button, *not* the Also Move to Trash one.
2) Go to the Finder or Terminal and rearrange your files in folders to your heart's content.
3) Select all the top-level files and folders and drag them back into your project.  When given the choice, choose Create Groups for Added Folders.

You'll now have a group hierarchy that follows the directory hierarchy on disk.

You'll need to make sure all the proper files get back into their correct build phases and targets. It's best to do this one target at a time in a multi-target project.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the group hierarchy then follows the disk hierarchy UNTIL THE DISK HIERARCHY CHANGES, right?

Comment: Also, if you afterwards move files around in the project, that are in one physical folder and should move into another physical folder, they wont move there. So this method is useless. Coming from Eclipse I have to say Xcode is really messy with its file management.

Comment: It is possible to copy entire folder to cache from NSMainBundle,If it is possible how can i do that.

Comment: its 2016 and file management for ios projects is still awful.